# Switch content when mouse enter

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to display different content when **mouseenter**. My current coding is displaying content that I want to display when mouseenter but it keeping the previous content on show too. Check out my coding below. How do I switch those content?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#1").mouseenter(function() {
    $("#a1").show();
  });
  $("#2").mouseenter(function() {
    $("#a2").show();
  });
  $("#3").mouseenter(function() {
    $("#a3").show();
  });
});
```

```css
.content ul {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a id="1">number 1</a></li>
  <li><a id="2">number 2</a></li>
  <li><a id="3">number 3</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="content">
  <ul id="a1">
    // li statement
  </ul>
  <ul id="a2">
    // li statement
  </ul>
  <ul id="a3">
    // li statement
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're showing elements but you never hide any. Hide them first:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#1").mouseenter(function() {
    $('.content >ul').hide()
    $("#a1").show();
  });
  $("#2").mouseenter(function() {
    $('.content >ul').hide()
    $("#a2").show();
  });
  $("#3").mouseenter(function() {
    $('.content >ul').hide()
    $("#a3").show();
  });
});
```

```css
.content ul {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a id="1">number 1</a></li>
  <li><a id="2">number 2</a></li>
  <li><a id="3">number 3</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="content">
  <ul id="a1">
    // li statement 1
  </ul>
  <ul id="a2">
    // li statement 2
  </ul>
  <ul id="a3">
    // li statement 3
  </ul>
</div>
```

You could reduce your code even further to:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#1, #2, #3").mouseenter(function() {
    $('.content >ul').hide()
    $("#a" + this.id).show();
  });
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#1, #2, #3").mouseenter(function() {
    $('.content >ul').hide()
    $("#a" + this.id).show();
  });
});
```

```css
.content ul {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a id="1">number 1</a></li>
  <li><a id="2">number 2</a></li>
  <li><a id="3">number 3</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="content">
  <ul id="a1">
    // li statement 1
  </ul>
  <ul id="a2">
    // li statement 2
  </ul>
  <ul id="a3">
    // li statement 3
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't quite got the perfect answer, and although the answer you have solves your issue it leaves you with a lot of repeating code. From a quick play something like http://codepen.io/graingeri/pen/mWyJNG might help. Same code below:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("li:nth-child(1)").mouseenter(function() {
  $("li:nth-child(2)").show();
 $("li:nth-child(1)").mouseleave(function() {
  $("li:nth-child(2)").hide();
  });
 });
});
```

```css
li:nth-child(2) {
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
 <ul class="content">
  <li id="first">Test</li>
  <li>Hello</li>
 </ul>
</div>
```